# Editing exposure time and region for Android

Tags: android

Working on a project of mine, I need to be able to manipulate the exposure time and set it accordingly and well as the exposure region.  I was hoping someone could give me some pointers in this area?  Do I need to access the Camera API for Android?

I am using Eclipse for development.

You're thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try Camera.Parameter's exposure compensation calls. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation%28int%29

And you can only change parameters described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html